# utf8 and utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have problem inserting rows to my DB.
When a row contains characters like: 'è', 'ò', 'ò', '€', '²', '³' .... etc ... it returns an error like this (charset set to *utf8*):

```
Incorrect string value: '\xE8 pass...' for column 'descrizione' at row 1 - INSERT INTO materiali.listino (codice,costruttore,descrizione,famiglia) VALUES ('E 251-230','Abb','Relè passo passo','Relè');
```

But, if I set the charset to *latin1* or *utf8_general_ci* it works fine, and no errors are found.

Can somebody explain me why does this happens? I always thought that *utf8* was "larger" than *latin1*

EDIT: I also tried to use mysql_real_escape_string, but the error was always the same!!!!

Comment: There is no `utf8` charset in MySQL. What charset do you use when having error?

Comment: @webbandit: [Yes there is](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-unicode-sets.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-charsets.html) for UTF-8, the default collation is `utf8_general_ci`.
If you want a specific order in your alphabet that is not the `general_ci` one, you should pick one of the `utf8_*` collation that are provided for the `utf8` charset, whichever match your requirements in term of ordering.

Both your table and your connection to the DB should be encoded in `utf8`, preferably the same collation, [read more about setting connection collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html).

To be completely safe you should check your *table collation* and make sure it's `utf8_*` and that your connection is too, using the complete syntax of **SET NAMES**

```
SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
```

You can find information about the different collation [here](http://www.collation-charts.org/)

Comment: I finally worked it out with your solution -> "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'".. thanks a lot!

Comment: You may consider accepting my answer then ;-) And I'm glad it helps.

Answer (score 5):

[`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) is not relevant, as it merely escapes string termination quotes that would otherwise enable an attacker to inject SQL.

`utf8` is indeed "larger" than `latin1` insofar as it is capable of representing a superset of the latter's characters.  However, not every byte-sequence represents valid `utf8` characters; whereas every possibly byte sequence does represent valid `latin1` characters.

Therefore, if MySQL receives a byte sequence it expects to be `utf8` (but which isn't), some characters could well trigger this "incorrect string value" error; whereas if it expects the bytes to be `latin1` (even if they're not), they will be accepted - but incorrect data may be stored in the table.

Your problem is almost certainly that your connection character set does not match the encoding in which your application is sending its strings.  Use the `SET NAMES` statement to change the current connection's character set, e.g. `SET NAMES 'utf8'` if your application is sending strings encoded as UTF-8.

Read about [connection character sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-connection.html) for more information.

As an aside, `utf8_general_ci` is not a character set: it's a *collation* for the `utf8` character set. [The manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-general.html) explains:

> A ***character set*** is a set of symbols and encodings. A ***collation*** is a set of rules for comparing characters in a character set.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");
```

Eurika, the above did it :-)