# Is Mysql collation utf_8 and utf8_general_ci are similar

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

Is there is any difference between  mysql collation **utf_8** and **utf8_general_ci** formats.

I got a support ticket to update all my sql tables to **utf8_general_ci** format instead of **utf_8** .

The **subject** of the ticket is

> "To allow a better interoperability and exchange of information
>   between systems across the world. Although this doesn't necessarily
>   impact your performance or security we advise you setting your
>   database tables to the "utf8_general_ci"

Please help me..

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have a collation available named `utf_8` ? The most common are `utf8_general_ci`, `utf8_bin` and `utf8_unicode_ci`..

Comment: Make a backup and try'n'error with a few smaller tables containing utf8 characters.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to confuse collation and character set.

- A character set defines which characters are known.
- A collation defines a sort order in a character set. This is necessary for comparisons.

Your character set is utf8, your collation is utf8_general_ci.

So, actually you have to do nothing.

```
create table colly(a varchar(2) collate utf8_general_ci);

select * from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'playground' 
and table_name = 'colly'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           TABLE_CATALOG: NULL
            TABLE_SCHEMA: playground
              TABLE_NAME: colly
             COLUMN_NAME: a
        ORDINAL_POSITION: 1
          COLUMN_DEFAULT: NULL
             IS_NULLABLE: YES
               DATA_TYPE: varchar
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH: 2
  CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH: 6
       NUMERIC_PRECISION: NULL
           NUMERIC_SCALE: NULL
      CHARACTER_SET_NAME: utf8
          COLLATION_NAME: utf8_general_ci
             COLUMN_TYPE: varchar(2)
              COLUMN_KEY:
                   EXTRA:
              PRIVILEGES: select,insert,update,references
          COLUMN_COMMENT:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Don't know what you mean with your comment, but here those two lines

```
      CHARACTER_SET_NAME: utf8
          COLLATION_NAME: utf8_general_ci
```

indicate what I said above.

Comment: Your are correct, but when you query the information scheme for getting the collation (field : COLLATION_NAME) it shows both utf_8 and  utf8_general_ci.

Comment: @BalaVaradarajan Edited my answer, though I don't understand yet, what the problem exactly is. Please clarify if my edit doesn't solve it.

Comment: Thanks @fancyPants : What i am saying is i am getting both the values utf8 & utf8_general_ci in the field COLLATION_NAME:

Comment: Well, the thing is, there is no collation named simply utf8 (at least not delivered by MySQL), and even if you made your own collation, it's not possible to have multiple collations on the same column. Can you post the result of `show create table your_table_name` and the result from querying information_schema like I did?

Answer (score 0):

utf8 is the character set and utf8_general_ci is the collation sequence (how characters are compared) Here's a preveious post that explains this well.

[utf8 and utf8_general_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597153/utf8-and-utf8-general-ci)